# padding between col-md2 elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My goal is to show 6 columns in one row. Here's part of how I get them done (shown only first 3).

I have this code:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input mytr="first_name" mytrId="" name="first_name[]" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" type="text">
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <input mytr="middle_name" mytrId="" name="middle_name[]" id="middle_name"      class="form-control" placeholder="Middle name" type="text">
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <input mytr="last_name" mytrId="" name="last_name[]" id="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" type="text">
</div>
```

It produces the following controls with padding between them:

[image]

I'd like the editors to have only 1px of padding and get them as close to one another as possible.

What do I add to the class for this? if possible at all?

Comment: twitter bootstrap?? which version?? how many columns in a row, 4?

Comment: Sorry: Twitter bootstrap 3.3.2 , yes, version 6 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `.col-md-2` padding values. In the following HTML I added the `.little-padding` class to use and make the different padding.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row little-padding">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input mytr="first_name" mytrid="" name="first_name[]" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input mytr="middle_name" mytrid="" name="middle_name[]" id="middle_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle name" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input mytr="last_name" mytrid="" name="last_name[]" id="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can have this CSS. Instead of `padding-left:15px;` and `padding-right:15px;` (which is the Bootstrap's default values) I gave `padding-left:0;` and `padding-right:1px;`.

After that, I gave the default padding values for the first and last child so that the `.col-md-2` divs stay inside the `.row`.

```
.row.little-padding .col-md-2 {padding-right:1px; padding-left:0;}
.row.little-padding .col-md-2:first-child {padding-left:15px;}
.row.little-padding .col-md-2:last-child {padding-right:15px;}
```

[Here](http://www.bootply.com/eZkL36AmJa) is a working demo.

**Note**: If you want this behavior with other classes you need to use the `[class^="col-"]` selector which applies to all `col-*` classes ([demo here](http://www.bootply.com/2OjWdYRbBu)) but it might not work an all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with col's padding or use [**form-inline**](http://www.bootply.com/DMKDxVmMjN), for more info check [**forms**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).